# join in opposition by someone

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

I am puzzled by the sentence :

> Doctors,academics and newspapers were joined in opposition by the police and judges ,who warned that the reforms were "close to lunacy".

Does it means that :

> Doctors,academics and newspapers and police and judge all disagree the reforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does mean what you say. The police and judges joined with the doctors etc. in opposing the reforms.

Answer (score 0):

Because you quoted only part of the sentence, I cannot be sure. if the sentence is

> Doctors, academics, and newspapers were joined in opposition by the police and the judge.

Then indeed it means

> Doctors, academics, newspapers, police and the judge were all opposed.